# Docker containers on user defined bridge networks can't communicate

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I'm using docker on my Ubuntu 20.10 machine. I'd like to use docker-compose to set up a few containers on a user defined bridge network.

My current setup for my `docker_compose.yml` is as follows:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  webserver:
    image: httpd
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.0.2

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.0.0/16
          gateway: 172.16.0.1
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc: "true"
      com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade: "true"
      com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4: "0.0.0.0"
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: "docker1"
```

Running `docker-compose up` works fine and creates the network with the container, and if I try to interact with the container from the host:

```
wget 172.16.0.2
```

It works as I would expect it  to. However, when I try to add another container to the network and attempt to connect to it, i.e:

```
docker run --rm -it --net=test1_default alpine wget 172.16.0.2
```

The added container is unable to connect. It's also worth noting that no container on the network is able to access the internet either.

I remembered being able to interact between containers fine that were added to the **default bridge network**, so I created a modified `docker-compose.yml` just to test it out:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  webserver:
    image: httpd
    network_mode: bridge
```

It was given the IP `172.17.0.2`. Trying the same command as before on the this network:

```
docker run --rm -it --net=bridge alpine wget 172.17.0.2
```

works perfectly fine! I also tried to ping `8.8.8.8` and the containers appear to connect to the internet fine as well.

I don't believe this is a problem with docker-compose creating the bridge network because I encounter the same issue if I create the docker network manually and try adding containers to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm happy to provide more information on the host system configuration as well.

Comment: That seems like a rather complex configuration for a basic setup.  If you delete both `networks:` blocks in their entirety, can you connect from the other container using something like `docker run --rm --net=test1_default alpine wget webserver`, using the Compose service name as a host name?  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes the overall environment a little more; in the core Docker network terminology, Compose (v2/v3 `docker-compose.yml`) always uses a "user-defined" bridge network, maybe an automatically-created one named `default`.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to have the network defined in the docker-compose file so I could assign static IPs  to the containers. I don't necessarily need it for what I'm working on, but unfortunately the bridge network that's created automatically by docker-compose has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems trivial, but I was able to resolve the issue by uninstalling docker and reinstalling. My guess is that something got screwed up in my recent upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.10

Answer (score -3):

Try the official documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network-configuration-reference and here https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/, you should read about --link tags

Comment: Please provide some examples and explanations. Not only links to official docs